# Effect of 2ASK Sampling Points on Bit Rate

Tags: communication, matlab, modulation, sampling

"I reduced the **only one sampling points** while using 2ASK modulation, and the bit error rate increased by 20%. Can you help me with this?"

Question happens in this line **t = 0:bitDuration/100:bitDuration;**

sorry for not postting picture, i tried but failed.

```
% clear;
% close all;
% clc;

% Set Parameters
bitRate = 1000; % Bit Rate（bps）
carrierFreq = 10000; % Carrier Frequency（Hz）
bitDuration = 1 / bitRate; % Bit Duration（s）

% **question happens here**
t = 0:bitDuration/100:bitDuration;
% t = 0:bitDuration/100:(bitDuration-bitDuration/100);

% Generate tx data
data = randi([0 1], 1, 1000);

% 2ASK modulation
amplitude1 = 1; % 
amplitude0 = 0; % 
modulatedSignal = zeros(1, length(data) * length(t));


index = 1;
for i = 1:length(data)
    if data(i) == 1
        modulatedSignal(index:index+length(t)-1) = amplitude1 * cos(2*pi*carrierFreq*t);
    else
        modulatedSignal(index:index+length(t)-1) = amplitude0 * cos(2*pi*carrierFreq*t);
    end
    index = index + length(t);
end

% Add noise
SNR_dB = 10; % dB
SNR_linear = power(10, SNR_dB/10); % 线性信噪比
noise_power_linear = power(bitDuration,2)/SNR_linear; % 噪声功率（线性）
noise_power_dBmW = pow2db(noise_power_linear*1000); % 噪声功率（dBmW）
noise_std_deviation_linear = sqrt(noise_power_linear/2); % 噪声标准差（线性）
noise_std_deviation_dBmW = pow2db(noise_std_deviation_linear*1000); % 噪声标准差（dBmW）
noise = noise_std_deviation_linear * randn(size(modulatedSignal)); % 添加噪声
receivedSignal = modulatedSignal + noise;

% 2ASK demodulation
demodulatedData = zeros(1, length(data));
index = 1;
for i = 1:length(data)
    receivedSymbol = receivedSignal(index:index+length(t)-1);
    demodulatedData(i) = sum(receivedSymbol .* cos(2*pi*carrierFreq*t)) / length(t);
    index = index + length(t);
end
demodulatedData = (demodulatedData >= (amplitude1 + amplitude0) / 2);

% Calculate Bit Error Rate
errorRate = sum(data ~= demodulatedData) / length(data);
fprintf('Ber：%.4f\n', errorRate);

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FlRY.png
```